# render html no formatting

Tags: html

How can I get WordPress to render a page without it adding any addtional html? I'm trying to build a dialog that will work on mobile devices and I only want to show that dialog and not have any of the standard wordpress content around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your own hook for `template_redirect` action:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse8170_template_redirect', 1 );
function wpse8170_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;

    // check if it is not a page or if it is front page, then exit from the hook
    if ( !$wp_query->is_page() || $wp_query->is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    // check queried object, if it is not a specific page, then exit from the hook
    $page = get_queried_object();
    if ( $page->ID != 777 ) { // your page ID 
        return;
    }

    // render header
    get_header();

    // ... render your content here ....

    // render footer
    get_footer();

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. This is an excellent solution. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new template, add your loops, etc, without the HTML present in your desktop site. This is the only way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Header and footer should be also dealt with, no?

Comment: "Not have any of the standard Wordpress content around it" seemed like header and footer should be removed. **Can the poster clarify?**

Comment: You should post the comment in the Question itself. Note that many times you need to use `@username` to address other user. But the author of the Question (or Answer) is always notified, depends on the situation. :::: Just in case: @spinlock, can you give the answerers some feedback?

Comment: @smithandteam is correct in that I don't want to add WordPress' header and footer. FYI - the usecase is to show a dialog to mobile users and jquery-mobile was conflicting with the rest of the theme. My solution is to isolate the dialog and serve up a stripped down page with jquery-mobile to get the user's response and return to the rest of the site.